# How to rename many filename with basename

Tags: javascript

I have many file with base name like that:

```
CashReport-Processed_637383195060155371
CashReport-Processed_637383195060115372
CashReport-Processed_637383159460155371
```

What solution for me to change all filename to CashReport-Processed using Javascripts
I using regex

```
const reg = /^CashReport_[\d]{18}.xml$/
```

But I don't know how to apply to change filename.
Example I read all file in my folder:

```
const directory = 'C:/Users/trand/Downloads';
var files = fs.readdirSync('C:/Users/trand/Downloads');
```

Comment: Wouldn't that result in trying to save multiple files with the same name ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I want change filename for compare 2 file, the action download many time so I want change filename for do it

Comment: what name you wants to change to? are those all same type of files? also in your comment you said `download many time`, maybe you wants to delete duplicates?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_renamesync_oldpath_newpath